# postgresql date_trunc() function in javascript

Tags: javascript, postgresql

What would be an alternative of postgresql `date_trunc()` function in javascript?
If I typed in pgsql the following:

```sql
select date_trunc('month', now())
```

I'd get `'2015-08-01 00:00:00-07'`

How to achieve the same with a javascript function?

```js
function dateTruncate(interval, date) {
 return ???;
}
```

Comment: [Maybe the MDN Date object documentation will help you find the APIs to do what you want.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using moment:

```
function dateTruncate(interval, date) {
    return moment(date).startOf(interval).toDate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using MomentJS

```js
$("#result").text(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00Z"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: this solution only takes care of truncating to the month. month should be a  variable